# <li dir="..."> breaks list indicators

Tags: html, css, html-lists, direction

Is there a way to apply `dir` tags to `<li>` elements and not mess up the list indicators? Intuitively, they should all be at the same side and RTL `<li>` elements in an otherwide LTR document should either align to the left if it's only a single underfull line, or else from the right. Why do the reversed direction indicators end up so far in the margin anyway?

```css
ul {
  max-width: 15em;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<body>
  <ul dir="ltr" lang="en">
    <li>English</li>
    <li dir="rtl" lang="ar">العربية</li>
    <li>English</li>
  </ul>
  <ul dir="rtl" lang="ar">
    <li>العربية</li>
    <li dir="ltr" lang="en">English</li>
    <li>العربية</li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works perfect. You can do it just by applying css:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
  ul {
    direction: rtl;
  max-width: 15em;
  margin: auto;
}
.ltr{
  direction : ltr;
}
.rtl{
  direction :  rtl;
}
</style>
<body>
  <ul class="ltr" lang="en">
    <li>English</li>
    <li   lang="ar">العربية</li>
    <li>English</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="rtl"  lang="ar">
    <li>العربية</li>
    <li  lang="en">English</li>
    <li>العربية</li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Even simpler would be to just add `li { direction: inherit; }` to the original CSS. But why is the Arabic text still shown correctly after the direction is overridden to LTR?

Answer (score 0):

"*Why do the reversed direction indicators end up so far in the margin anyway?*"

Because you have applied a `max-width:15em` to the `ul`. So the child list items will take full width of the parent and ended up in this way.

"*Is there a way to apply `dir` tags to `<li>` elements and not mess up the list* *indicators?*"

**Workaround 1:**

If you are not bothered about the inconsistent alignment of list indicators and need them to follow the direction, make the `ul` an `inline` element. without giving a specific width.

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 15em;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<body>
  <ul dir="ltr" lang="en">
    <li>English</li>
    <li dir="rtl" lang="ar">العربية</li>
    <li>English</li>
  </ul>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <ul dir="rtl" lang="ar">
    <li>العربية</li>
    <li dir="ltr" lang="en">English</li>
    <li>العربية</li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

**Workaround 2:**

Use `list-style-position: inside` property in `ul`. This property align the bullets with the text.

```css
ul {
  max-width: 15em;
  margin: auto;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<body>
  <ul dir="ltr" lang="en">
    <li>English</li>
    <li dir="rtl" lang="ar">العربية</li>
    <li>English</li>
  </ul>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <ul dir="rtl" lang="ar">
    <li>العربية</li>
    <li dir="ltr" lang="en">English</li>
    <li>العربية</li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```